# tfs 2013 incremental build number across build definitions

Tags: msbuild

I am wondering how you could implement an incremental build number that is shared by several different build definitions.  For example, I one build definition for our staging environment which has a build number of say 15.3.6.1.  I then queue a build for production, different build definition, I want that build number to be 15.3.6.2 instead of 15.3.6.1.  Is this possible with TFS 2013 builds, whether out of the box or through an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a PowerShell script that is modifying the Build Number Format parameter of the production build definition. Then you call this script as a post-build script from the staging build definition.